# pip conflict with the backend dependencies

Tags: pip, couchbase

Started since yesterday morning, I keep getting this error when I tried to "*pip*-install" `couchbase`:

> ERROR: Some build dependencies for couchbase==3.2.7 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/b1/b77badb03e77a9ee9e20c6b9a4374e892aaaffa80600e3287f9567d7fde8/couchbase-3.2.7.tar.gz#sha256=76d9c81197b55d04890f9834f5c4599888f58f1bfeaba50a708d659b920f8dae (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) conflict with the backend dependencies: typing-extensions==4.4.0 is incompatible with typing-extensions==3.7.4.3; python_version<"3.8".

I have no idea why typing-extensions now requires 4.4.0 version.

I tried adding `typing-extensions==3.7.4.3` to `requirements.txt` file and it didn't help.
I removed all other packages from `requirements.txt file` and only had `couchbase==3.2.7` and I still got the same error.

Tried this on macOS with Python version is 3.7.15.

I ended up installing a cached couchbase.whl file directly which solves the problem, not sure what's wrong with the file downloaded from pythonhosted.org

Comment: Maybe it would help if you could edit your question to mention  at least the Python interpreter version and operating system.

Comment: The same error manifests on Linux. Seems like a bug in dependency tree — the package requires `typing-extensions==3.7.4.3` but some dependency requires`typing-extensions==4.4.0`.

Comment: The weird thing is it was working a few days ago, and I haven't changed anything since.

Comment: Seems like one of those cases where pinning could have helped. -- Anwyay, maybe this is worth investigating; identify what changed in the past few days that causes pip's resolution algorithm to choke, identify which libraries got an update recently that broke this. -- Maybe it is even worth posting this to _pip_'s issue tracker, in case pip's dependency resolution algorithm needs a fix.

Comment: Can you try `python3 -m pip install couchbase==3.2.7 --no-use-pep517` ?

Answer (score 0):

## Dont do python3 -m pip install couchbase==3.2.7 --no-use-pep517!!!

### Solution 1: Override pip wheel isolation

You can to override pip wheel building isolation

```
pip install cmake scikit-build==0.15.0
pip install couchbase==3.2.7 --no-build-isolation
```

### Solution 2: Build and modify from source package

Ok so, without going too deep I think that `python 3.7` now comes with some default packages `typing-extensions==4.4.0`  (or maybe is a Ubuntu package, well it doesn't matter.)

The error complains that:

`typing-extensions==4.4.0 is incompatible with typing-extensions==3.7.4.3; python_version<"3.8"`

which in plain English translates in: *Hey, your Python version is 3.8, and you must have `typing-extensions==3.7.4.3` in your envrironment but you have version `4.4.0`!*

Right, so let's fix it.

### Fix

1. Open a terminal and enable the environment you need

```
cd myrepo
source env/bin/activate
(env) user$ >>>
```

1. Go to : [/couchbase/3.2.7/](https://pypi.org/project/couchbase/3.2.7/) and check the section : **Local Instal**
2. Create a directory called python_sdk

```
mkdir python_sdk
cd python sdk
```

3. Clone the repo at the version `3.2.7` and enter it

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch 3.2.7 https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client.git
cd couchbase-python-client/
```

4. Now with a text editor or vim into `requirements.txt` and comment out this line (currently at line 2)

```
# typing-extensions==3.7.4.3; python_version<"3.8"
```

5. Now install, **IMPORTANT!!! Make sure you activated the env in step 1**

```
python -m pip install .
```

It should be installed